# Starting An Inquiry Concerning Human Understanding. Will this be fun?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, hume, mind

As someone with a deep interest in philosophy and the intricacies of human understanding, I have decided to embark on an exciting intellectual journey, delving into the realm of David Hume's "An Inquiry Concerning Human Understanding."

Before I begin this endeavor, I'd like to reach out to this vibrant community to seek your thoughts and experiences. Has anyone here explored Hume's work extensively? If so, could you share your insights or offer any advice for someone starting this inquiry?

My aim is not only to grasp the philosophical concepts presented by Hume but also to make this learning experience enjoyable. Do you think studying "An Inquiry Concerning Human Understanding" can be fun, given its complexity and depth? I'd love to hear your perspectives and experiences on this matter.

Comment: maybe? i've read hume, and he's a great philosopher, though i found it a little irritating that he kept asking the reader to find counter arguments. my therapist implied he sounded psychotic, but i just wondered if he thought he was talking to simpletons

Comment: A certain model of *comprehension* appeals to me, but I'm afraid that doesn't bode well for *everybody*. Perhaps we can look for equivalents of *I (non) intelligo.*

Comment: Fun is different for everyone. How should we be able to judge this for you? I, for once, had quite a lot of fun reading it, making notes, and posing questions I wanted answered by the text.

Comment: It’s a good thing that this question is not “opinion based” or they would close it. 

Comment: "*David Hume could out-consume Schopenhauer and Schlegel...*"

Comment: When fun insights into human understanding are a priority, I turn to the contemporary philosophy of [Bill Burr](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=2O2bKu-3U3U&pp=ygUSQmlsbCBidXJyIHN0YW5kIHVw).

Answer (score 1):

It will! I heartily recommend this Very Bad Wizards episode [249: PHLEGM AND CARELESSNESS (on Hume's essay "THE SCEPTIC")](https://verybadwizards.fireside.fm/249), as illustrative of how thoughtful readable and provocative Hume's work is, and fun to discuss.

Of pivotal works in the Western philosophical canon, Hume's 'An Enquiry Concerning Human Understanding' is one of the most readable, and makes a great case for the role of making sense of our world in ordinary language and accessible form, and remains pretty contemporary in tone and relevance. Like the 'On Miracles' sectio. really wraps up a whole area of religious weaselry.